# Issue - The final local variable od cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type

Tags: java

When I try to declare a variable (like an int) inside a method or in curly brackets and then I want to change the value of the variable later on outside of the curly brackets it doesn't seem to work.Am I doing something wrong?How do I get it to work?I am relatively new to Java so sorry if this seems like a very basic question.

```
            Timer t = new Timer();
            t.schedule(new TimerTask(){
                public void run(){
                    double od = 0.5;
                }
            },30000);}
```

I want to change the value of od later on outside the curly brackets.How do I do that?

Comment: declare it outside of the run block.

Comment: make it `instance` member (variable)

Comment: @Braj But an instance variable of the enclosing type would be shared for all anonymous timer instances..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable is available only in the scope it was declared. In your case the scope is inside the `run()` method. If you want it available outside - it should be declared outside.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    final MyObj  obj = new MyObj();
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(new TimerTask(){
        public void run(){
            obj.set(0.5);
        }
    },500);

    System.out.println(obj.get());

}

private static class MyObj {
    private double od;
    public void set(double val) {
        od = val;
    }
    public double get() {
        return od;
    }
}
```

**Remark:**
A good rule of thumb is to declare the variable in the smaller (most specific) scope possible, in order to help GC deal with unused objects.

Comment: I tried this but it still didn't work.I still couldn't change the value of od outside the t.schedule() block of code.

Comment: @noobProgrammer you can't change the value outside cause it has to be declared `final` in order to be used by an inner class. That said, you can create an object that will hold/set that value for you: see the edit in my answer.

Comment: I tried to use the getter and setter methods.Inside the timertask,od would be 0.5 but once outside of the timertask od would change to 0.Is there a reason for that

Comment: @noobProgrammer you must have done something wrong, please post your code.

Comment: http://codetidy.com/4747/    This is just a portion of the code but it contains all the elements I have mentioned.

Comment: http://codetidy.com/4751/  Hmm.well they seem identical but it still doesn't work.the value of od is still zero for me.

Comment: is there something wrong with the code besides the getter/setter methods and timer?

Comment: Seeing the code that shows how do you check `od` value might explain it.

Comment: @noobProgrammer Please submit a full working example (that doesn't print what you want). I can't really understand what's wrong when you show me only a small portion of the code.

Comment: what do you mean (that doesn't print what I want)

Comment: @noobProgrammer I meant: post the whole code, in a way that I'll be able to copy and paste it into my IDE, run it and see what it prints.

Comment: @noobProgrammer I think that you're aiming too high, you should start with basics before you deal with more advanced stuff. That said, I refactored and fixed the code, it's still far away from ideal, but it's now working: http://codetidy.com/4755/ I also added a couple of comments in the code you posted.

Comment: Oh by the way how should i "start with the basics".I've studied a book or two on Java so is there something else I should do? Like write a slightly more simple program or go even deeper with my studies on Java.

Comment: @noobProgrammer First thing's first: read "clean code" and try to implement. Also read "effective java" to have better understanding of core concepts. That should keep you busy for a while ;)

Answer (score 3):

Variable `od` in your code is a local variable. By its nature it cannot be changed from outside the class.

There are several ways of achieving the effect that you want. One is replacing the anonymous class that you defined (i.e. the one within the curly braces) with a named class, and a setter for the `od` variable:

```
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    private double od = 0.5;
    public void run(){
        System.out.println(od);
    }
    public double getOd() {return od;}
    public void setOd(double val) {od = val;}
}
...
MyTimerTask task = new MyTimerTask();
t.schedule(task, 30000);
...
// At this point you can change od
task.setOd(2.3);
```